# Can't Use String Variable in NSURL?

Tags: swift, nsurl

I have a variable `copiedURL` which contains a URL `string`, I am trying to use that string variable to display an image programmatically

```
let url = NSURL(string: copiedURL)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let image2 = UIImage(data: data!)
```

When I build and run I get a **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I am certain that `copiedURL` has a value because I used `print()` to debug and everything printed just fine.

Also, I also tried:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "\(copiedURL)")
```

but that didn't solve it.

Comment: When I print the the value of `copiedURL` I copied and pasted the output into my web browser and the web page loaded as it should have. I appreciate your advice, but given the fact that the web page loaded, doesn't that mean the URL is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSURL(string:)` is a failable initializer. In the case that the URL isn't valid, it will not initialize a new `NSURL` instance, but will instead return `nil`.

Check that your `copiedURL` is a valid URL.

Comment: Restating my response from above, the value of `copiedURL` works just fine in my web browser, so logically I assume it's valid URL but I tried   `        let validURL = copiedURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())` and the issue is still there

Comment: Are you sure the error is at `url!` and not `data!`? Step through with the debugger and see what happens.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just checked and the error message was pointing to `let image2 = UIImage(data: data!)`, with that being said, what further steps can I take to fix this?

Comment: You've provided so little context about your code or your problem space, I'm not sure exactly what you expect us to pull out of our hats

Comment: With all due respect, I thought I provided enough details about my problem. I am having difficulty with this because I don't know what additional steps I personally can take beyond what I've already tried. One thing I noticed when debugging is if I took the value of `copiedURL` and did this `let url = NSURL(string: "valueOfCopiedURL")` then everything runs just fine with no errors. So I don't understand why replacing a string **value** with a string **variable** causes a bug.

Comment: There's something you might wanted to have mentioned in the first place. For all I knew, that URL could've point to data that wasn't an image. Check the value of the data object when you use a string *variable*, and compare it to what happens when you use a string *consant*.

Comment: Take this is a lesson in why you shouldn't abuse the `!`. When you have so many force unwraps, it becomes hard to track which ones worked and which ones failed.

Comment: Lesson learned. When I compared the data objects, the instance with the variable returned **nil**